# Python Networkx centrality measure range of nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-science, networkx

How do I select a range from given values when drawing `degree_centrality` graph.

```
B1:  0.64
E2: 0.61
C3: 0.60
B2: 0.58
M1: 0.50
C1: 0.328
R1: 0.228
```

```
def draw(G, pos, measures, measure_name):
    
    nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=250, cmap=plt.cm.plasma, 
                                   node_color=list(measures.values()),
                                   nodelist=measures.keys())
    nodes.set_norm(mcolors.SymLogNorm(linthresh=0.01, linscale=1, base=10))
    # labels = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
    edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)

    plt.title(measure_name)
    plt.colorbar(nodes)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=675)
```

```
draw(G, pos, nx.degree_centrality(G), 'Degree Centrality')
```

I am trying to use Network [centrality measure visualisation](https://aksakalli.github.io/2017/07/17/network-centrality-measures-and-their-visualization.html)
to draw visualise centrality measure but i am only interested in visualising nodes within a range of values.

I only wany to visualise range 0.64 to 0.60 from the given range above.

```
B1:  0.64
E2: 0.61
C3: 0.60
```

Comment: You can just filter the list of nodes with for loop before the process (degree_centrality), that's just an idea!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to reduce the dictionary `measures`:

```py
def draw(G, pos, measures, measure_name):


    # reduce measures
    min_val, max_val = 0.1, 0.4
    measures = {k:v for k, v in measures.items() if v<=max_val and v>=min_val}

    ...
```

Note that the `min_val`, `max_val` can be added as arguments of the function or alternatively, the subsetting can be done before passing values to the function (so calculate the centrality measure separately, subset it, and only after pass it to the function).